# Nservce bus outgoing queues

Tags: nservicebus

I have two subscribers listening to a publisher.All th queues are on the same machine.To make subscriber power off i deleted the input queue of one of the subsriber. I am getting one exception in the generic host command output and no meesages are there in the Outgoing Queues. Is this behaviour is coz all things are in the same machine ?

Comment: Could you please post the exception detail?

Answer (score 2):

To bring down a subscriber, just kill the process - no need to delete the queue. The reason you don't see pending messages in the outgoing queue is exactly because the queue is local.

Comment: Suppose the subscriber on another machine.Just killing the process won't be enough since the subscription storage can access the subscriber queue that's why i delted the queue to make the testing like subscribre machine is shut down at the moment :)

Comment: If you don't want the subscriber to be delivered any more messages, you can Bus.Unsubscribe on shutdown. That being said, if you need to do this, it's likely that something isn't quite right in the architecture.